# Show details from the list item on a "task e-mail" Workflow

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, tasks

I have a list that I have a workflow on. The workflow sends a task e-mail. Every thing works as expected.

When the workflow runs the user gets an e-mail in Outlook they can click on to open the Infopath form for the task.

What I want to do is add details of that list item to the Infopath form in the task e-mail.

Any idea on how to do this?

**I know it is not possible to do this on the Initiation form. I am trying to do it on the task e-mail form.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a data source on your info path form & the make list as that & based on the item ID you will be able to get the list item details

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-data-connection-to-a-SharePoint-document-library-or-list-3233d77d-95af-4245-a124-dca2f6d5d02e

Comment: I can add the data source but how can I filter for the item that the workflow was run on?

Comment: With the ItemID... here is the link on how add list itemid in sharepoint workflow http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/124926/how-to-return-list-item-id-using-spd-custom-workflow

Comment: But that field does not exist in the task e-mail sub-workflows.

Comment: You can use the itemID & then it should have TaskID when the task is generated.. could you please explain what you are trying to do.